# Where did /usr/mdec come from?

Tags: unix

On UNIX, the boot code is traditionally found in the directory `/usr/mdec`.  Some modern UNIX variants keep this tradition up (e.g. OpenBSD) while others have changed the directory layout (e.g. FreeBSD).  I was able to find a `/usr/mdec` directory in [5th edition UNIX](https://minnie.tuhs.org//cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V5/usr/mdec), but not in any of the incomplete earlier versions.  No explanation for the name is given.

Where does the name `/usr/mdec` come from and what does it mean?

Comment: I suspect the `dec` part was chosen because the code is DEC-specific...

Comment: There are also [references](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V4-Snapshot-Development/man/man8/20boot.8) [to](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V4-Snapshot-Development/man/man8/bproc.8) [`mdec`](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V4-Snapshot-Development/man/man8/mkfs.8) in V4.

Comment: I suspect it to mean DEC as well - the directory contains **DEC** **m**achine specific boot code

Answer (score 9):

These directories have such terse names, don't they? And the etymology is not always documented, nor obvious. In many cases, the etymology of a name in UNIX is simply lost to obscurity.

But the directory you're asking about appears to contain images for **m**agtapes and **DEC**tapes, at least to begin with, or in the earliest versions of UNIX. From the manpage linked to by Stephen Kitt,

> The *tp* command places a bootstrap program on the otherwise unused block zero of the tape. The DECtape version of this program is called *tboot,* the magtape version *mboot.*

[There also is mention](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V4-Snapshot-Development/man/man8/mkfs.8) of a `/usr/mdec/uboot`, which is a bootstrap of the filesystem. I don't know whether that was a magtape or a DECtape.

Answer (score 4):

`/usr/mdec` contains machine-dependent code. [In V5](https://minnie.tuhs.org//cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V5/usr/mdec) it contains source code as well as programs; in V6 the source code was moved to [`/usr/source/mdec`](https://minnie.tuhs.org//cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/source/mdec).

That this is not just about magtapes and DECtapes is clear if you look at the contents, which include programs to format RK03/05 disk packs ([`rkf.s`](https://minnie.tuhs.org//cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V5/usr/mdec/rkf.s)), print to a terminal attached to a [KL-11](https://gunkies.org/wiki/KL11_Teletype_Control) serial interface ([`list.s`](https://minnie.tuhs.org//cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V5/usr/mdec/list.s)), an RK05 disk driver ([`rk.s`](https://minnie.tuhs.org//cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/source/mdec/rk.s)), low-level terminal-interface-specific getc()/putc()/etc. ([`tty.s`](https://minnie.tuhs.org//cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/source/mdec/tty.s), presumably for use in kernel debugging code or something like that), and so on.

It's not clear to me whether at the time this was considered an abbreviation of "Machine-dependent DEC code" or "Machine DEpendent Code"; either way it was eventually used in the latter sense in early '90s BSD ports, with files such as `/usr/mdec/boot.$MACHINE`. You can see various examples of this from the 2000s in [this search of `NetBSD/src` on GitHub](https://github.com/NetBSD/src/search?p=1&q=mdec&type=commits).